# Is $\log_{3}y = (x-2)\log_{3}k + \log_{3}h$ a valid linear form?

Tags: linear-transformations

I was asked to convert $y = hk^{x-2}$ to linear form.

I wound up with $\log_{3}y = x\log_{3}k - 2\log_{3}k + \log_{3}h$

Whereas the answer scheme demanded $\log_{3}y = (x-2)\log_{3}k  + \log_{3}h$

Are both of these acceptable? $X = (x-2)$ feels inherently off to me as it's not as simplified as it could be.

Comment: Use \log to produce $\log$. It looks much better. Also use MathJax properly everywhere. Btw, none of the answers are correct, unless you have $h \cdot k^{x-2}$ inside the logarithm.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between them algebraically?

$$ \log_3y=x\log_3k−2\log_3k+\log_3h= (x−2)\log_3k+\log_3h$$

can be also written

$$ x\log_3k+\log_3\frac{h}{k^2}$$

pulling constants to the RHS.

Btw, the base may be any real number in place of 3.

Comment: I think the OP's problem is that the standard form of a linear polynomial is $ax+b$ and not $a(x-c)+b$ as suggested by the answer scheme.